# How to insert data into database from the main file?

Tags: java, mysql, program-entry-point

I've got 2 file in my java project : MysqlConnect and Main .
I want to run query from Main class.It's possible?

***This is MysqlConnect file:***

```
public class MysqlConnect {

public Connection conn = null;
public String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
public String dbName = "jdbctutorial";
public String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public String userName = "birthday";
public String password = "123456";
public Statement stmt;
public String query = "";
public int rs;

public void crearedatabase() {
    try {

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        // System.out.println("Connected to the database");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Baza de date nu a fost creata");
    }

}

public void executeSql() {

    try {
        rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Mysql Error");
    }

}
}
```

And this is the ***Main file***:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
{



MysqlConnect sqlconnect = new MysqlConnect();   
sqlconnect.crearedatabase();

sqlconnect.query="INSERT INTO `jdbctutorial`.`persons` (`id`, `nume`, `prenume`, `data`) VALUES (NULL, 'xxxx', 'xxxx', '1990-12-12');";
sqlconnect.executeSql();
}

}
```

The error(Exception) is on the MysqConnection at the try/catch

```
rs = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: `It's possible???` Yes!!!  `The error(Exception) is on the MysqConnection at the try/catch` what error?  please post full stack.  Also, try getting rid of all the ` characters in your query

Comment: This error :java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MysqlConnect.executeSql(MysqlConnect.java:33)
 at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Comment: Try debugging.  Your `stmt` object is null for some reason.

Comment: Is null ? But if I print out the stmt variable is not empty("com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@16e9494")....

Answer (score 1):

You assign statement object to a local variable named `stmt` instead of the object field with the same name.
Replace this

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

With this:

```
this.stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

`this` is not necessary here, but it's a good practice to have it there.

Comment: Well spotted, can't believe I missed that.